# last sibling in jquery?

Tags: jquery

could someone help me to select last sibling of clicked element in jquery?

Comment: You should edit the question and make it : "last clicked sibling"

Comment: This question could benefit from some enhancement / context / coding attempt.  Please edit.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
$("#myElement").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(":last").hide();
});
```

Comment: Surprisingly, this is faster than `$(this).siblings().last()` or `$(this).parent().children().last();`. See http://jsperf.com/jquery-last-sibling

Comment: @RadekPech: The latter also gives different results whenever `this` refers to the last element.